# How to remove redundant Insert Statements from a Script to improve the performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I am creating a Script which has more than 700 INSERT statements

```
INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E]) VALUES (1, 1, N'a', N'p')
INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E]) VALUES (2, 1, N'x', N'o')
INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E]) VALUES (3, 1, N'y', N'u')
INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E]) VALUES (4, 1, N's', N't')
INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E]) VALUES (5, 1, N'y', N'w')
INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E]) VALUES (6, 1, N'z', N'z')
INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E]) VALUES (7, 1, N'k', N'f')
```

and so on....

I want to remove the redundant part

> INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E])

Is there any way to achieve this ?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**IMAGINATION :**

some thing like,

```
INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E]) MULTIPLE VALUES
   (1, 1, N'a', N'p')
 , (2, 1, N'x', N'o')
 , (3, 1, N'y', N'u')
 , (4, 1, N's', N't')
 , (5, 1, N'y', N'w')
 , (6, 1, N'z', N'z')
 , (7, 1, N'k', N'f')
```

please guide ... how can i improve the performance as well , as i have mentioned that i have 700 records to be added... from a single script..

Comment: Yes this is possible, just remove the `multiple`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx  See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07202/1

Comment: Possible in SQL Server by removing the Multiple. Not sure about other vendors.

Comment: If you supply all the columns in the table you do not need the first part:

Let's say you have columns A to E and C should always be null, then do this:

    INSERT tableName VALUES (1, 1, null, N'a', N'p')
    INSERT tableName VALUES (2, 1, null, N'x', N'o')
    INSERT tableName VALUES (3, 1, null, N'y', N'u')
    INSERT tableName VALUES (4, 1, null, N's', N't')
    INSERT tableName VALUES (5, 1, null, N'y', N'w')
    INSERT tableName VALUES (6, 1, null, N'z', N'z')
    INSERT tableName VALUES (7, 1, null, N'k', N'f')

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
INSERT tableName ([A], [B], [D], [E])  VALUES
   (1, 1, N'a', N'p')
 , (2, 1, N'x', N'o')
 , (3, 1, N'y', N'u')
 , (4, 1, N's', N't')
 , (5, 1, N'y', N'w')
 , (6, 1, N'z', N'z')
 , (7, 1, N'k', N'f')
```

i.e., simply remove the `MULTIPLE` from your query which you almost got it yourself.

Comment: will that be a performance improvement ?

Comment: @N.K:- Not exactly the performance improvement but yes this is a better way to avoid ambiguous column names when you are inserting multiple rows. :)